# Is the converse of this statement true?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

we know that:

> Ratios of scale functionals are location and scale invariant.

My question is: is it true that every scale and location 
invariant functional can be rewritten as the ratio of two scale
 and location equivariant functional?

It seems logical to me, but I can't find a source or a proof 
 for this.

---

**Edit:**

to respond to whuber's question below. Here I mean functional 
in the statistical sense; e.g a map from a set of probability 
distributions to the real numbers. 
Examples include the mean functional $\mu$:

$$\mu(F)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF(x),$$

on the set of distributions with finite first moments or the variance functional $\sigma^2$:

$$\sigma^2(F)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu(F))^2dF(x).$$

A non-negative functional $T$ is a scale functional if

$$T(G)=|\lambda|T(F)$$

when $G(x)=F((x-\mu)/\lambda)$ and $\lambda\neq0$ (i.e. if $T$ is 
scale equivariant and shift invariant).

A functional $T$ is a scale and shift invariant if

$$T(G)=T(F)$$

when $G(x)=F((x-\mu)/\lambda)$ and $\lambda\neq0$.

Comment: Because "functional" means different things in various branches of math, stats, (and physics), could you please provide a definition of what you mean by a "scale functional"?

Comment: Thank you: that comment reflected some remaining confusion on my part about the meaning of "equivariant." I think I have sorted it out now, in a proposed answer, so I will delete the comment to avoid extending my confusion to others!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my understanding of the terminology.  $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of all distributions on the real line.  For $F\in\mathcal{X}$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$,and $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}-{0}$, define a transformation from $F\to F$ *via*

$$(T_{\mu,\sigma}(F))(x) = F((x-\mu)/\sigma)(x)$$

for all $x\in \mathbb R$.  (This is the action of the affine group of the real line induced on the set of measures on the real line.)  A *functional* S is a map $S:\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{R}$.  It is *invariant* when

$$S[T_{\mu,\sigma}(F)] = S[F]$$

for all $F$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$, and it is *equivariant* when

$$S[T_{\mu,\sigma}(F)] = |\sigma|S[F]$$

for all *nondegenerate* $F$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$.

---

**The idea is to find a natural location and scale for all relevant distributions.**  Here is one way.

For all $F$ and $0\lt q \lt 1$, the set $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}\,|\, F(x)\ge q\}$$ is nonempty and must have a lower bound, whence it has a greatest lower bound $F_{[q]}$.  Define $$m(F) = F_{[1/2]}.$$  The set $$\{x\in \mathbb{R}_{+}\,|\, F(m(F)+x) - F(m(F)-x)\ge q\}$$ is bounded below by $0$ and nonempty, whence it must have a greatest lower bound $F^\prime_{[q]}$.  Moreover, for $q$ sufficiently large, this glb must be strictly positive *provided $F$ is nondegenerate*.  The set of such $q$ for which $F^\prime_{[q]} \gt 0$ has a greatest lower bound $q^\prime_F$.  Define  $$s(F) = F^\prime_{[(1-q)/2]}.$$

It follows that $m(F)$ (the location) and $s(F)$ (the scale) are well-defined and $s(F)\gt 0$.

It is straightforward to check that

$$m(T_{\mu,\sigma}(F)) = m(F) + \mu$$

and

$$s(T_{\mu,\sigma}(F)) = s(F)|\sigma|$$

for $\sigma\ne 0$ (which makes $s$ an equivariant functional).  Choosing $\mu=-m(F)$ and $\sigma = 1/s(F)$ yields a transformation

$$Z: F \to F^{0} = T_{-m(F),1/s(F)} (F)$$

which is well-defined on all non-degenerate distributions.  $F^{0}$ is the *standardized version* of $F$ and

$$F = T_{m(F),s(F)}(F^{0}).$$

In other words, *every nondegenerate distribution is a shifted and scaled version of its standardized version.*

---

**Here is one solution.**  Let $S$ be any invariant functional.  It is immediate that

$$S_1[F] = s(F)S[F^{0}]$$

defines an equivariant functional, exhibiting

$$S = \frac{S_1}{s}$$

explicitly as the ratio of two equivariant functionals, because $S[F] = S[F^{0}]$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have shown that when $F$ is non degenerate, every scale equivariant functional can be written as the product of a scale equivariant functional giving the scale of the standardized version of $F$ and a (scale) invariant functional?

Comment: Yes--now that I have fixed a typo in the definition of $S_1$!